# How to add users in ejabberd multi user chat?

Tags: django, ejabberd, multiuserchat, ejabberd-api

I was working on ejabberd chat, I'm able to create multiple user chat room with command

```
sudo ejabberdctl create_room mychat localhost xmpp_domain
```

I want to know how to create that in virtual host as it is not being created in virtual host and how to add user of virtual host to it.

Comment: your question is too general. Can you please narrow down the scope, what is you programming language preference, what have you tried so far... right now it's not possible to answer your question in a reasonable way.

Comment: @Farside  Actually, I'm implementing it to use with django project and want to use ejabberd rest api to create multi user chat. Also, till now I've added `mod_muc_admin: {}` in ejabberd.yml file. So, I'm able to create multiple user chat room with command `sudo ejabberdctl create_room mychat localhost xmpp_domain` but I want to know how to create that in virtual host as it is not being created in virtual host and how to add user of virtual host to it.

Comment: @Ankit what do u mean by "u want to create in a virtual host?" It's ambiguous. Please update your question with the things you have tried so far & the error u r getting in doing so

Comment: @Kumar I mean we have virtual host in ejabberd like localhost, under it we also have option of multi user chat, so under it I want to add users in a chat room.

Comment: @Kumar Even if you could help in adding user as it is not under virtual host, it would be okay.